# C++ extract actual type from universal reference

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, forwarding-reference

How can I extract the actual type of an universal reference like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T&& value) {
    otherFunction<...>(value);
```

I want to replace the `...` by the actual type of value, that is, neither `T&` or `T&&` or `const T&`, but just `T`.

Also, do I really need to `std::forward` the value? Because `otherFunction` only accepts actual values, so it'll drop any kind of reference anyway. So is it correct that I don't need to `std::forward`?

Comment: [`std::remove_reference_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::remove_reference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_reference/). It will turn `int`, `int&`, and `int&&` into `int`.

Comment: to be precise, either `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type`, or `std::remove_reference_t<T>`

Comment: You forgot to remove the cv-qualifier.